# Python 3.4: Trying to get full name results from nltk

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am a beginner in Python, and I am trying to collect the names from a txt and put them inside another txt file using NLTK. The issue is that only the first names are returned, without the surnames. Anything I can do? Here's the code:

```
    import nltk

# function start
def extract_entities(text):
    ind = len(text)-7
    sub = text[ind:]
    print(sub)
    output.write('\nPRODID=='+sub+'\n\n')
    for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(text):
        for chunk in nltk.ne_chunk(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))):
            if hasattr(chunk, 'label'):
                output.write(chunk.label()+':'+ ' '.join(c[0] for c in chunk.leaves())+'\n')

# function end

# main program
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("iso-8859-1")(sys.stdout, 'xmlcharrefreplace')
if sys.stdout.encoding != 'cp850':
  sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('cp850')(sys.stdout.buffer, 'strict')
if sys.stderr.encoding != 'cp850':
  sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('cp850')(sys.stderr.buffer, 'strict')
file = open('C:\Python34\Description.txt', 'r')
output = open('C:\Python34\out.txt', 'w')

for line in file:
 if not line : continue
 extract_entities(line)

file.close()
output.close()
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Could we have some info on how the data inside the text file is formatted? It would help with formulating the appropriate code.

Comment: It is raw text, I'm giving an example:

Comment: One row is: "Portrait of Nelson Mandela Nelson Rolihlahla Mandela was a South African anti-apartheid revolutionary, politician, and philanthropist who served as President of South Africa from 1994 to 1999, id:31652 ID==31652", so I should be gettind Nelson Mandela as a name returned, but I only get "Nelson" at the PERSON label of NLTK.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Using the exact string you quoted, I get the chunk `(PERSON
    Nelson/NNP
    Mandela/NNP
    Nelson/NNP
    Rolihlahla/NNP
    Mandela/NNP)` (since the title is stuck to the sentence). And your loop extracts the chunks correctly. Check your code again, and/or provide actual input *in your question* (you can edit it).